# How to avoid timestamps extracted from a changelog topic to trigger Processor::punctuate

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I'm writing a KafkaStreams (v2.1.0) application which reads messages from a regular Kafka topic, left-joins these messages with metadata from a compacted changelog topic and performs some stateful processing on the result using a Processor which also runs a punctuate call on regular time intervals based on event-time. The messages in the data-topic have a timestamp and a custom TimestampExtractor is defined (which defines the event-time as I'd like to use in the puctuate call). The messages in the metadata-topic, however, don't have a timestamp, but it seems KafkaStreams requires a TimestampExtractor to be defined anyhow. Now, if I use the embedded metadata in Kafka messages `ExtractRecordMetadataTimestamp` or just a `WallclockTimestampExtractor` it breaks the logic of my application because it seems these timestamps of the metadata-topic also trigger the punctuate call in my processor, but the event-time in my data topic can be hours behind the wall-clock time and I only want to have the punctuate-call trigger on these.

My question is how I can avoid the punctuate call to be triggered by  timestamps extracted from this compacted metadata topic?

One trick that seems to work at first sight is to always return 0 as the timestamp of these metadata messages, but I'm not sure that it will not have unwanted side-effects. Another workaround is not to rely on 'punctuate' altogether and implement my own tracking of the event time but I'd prefer to use the standard KafkaStreams approach. So maybe there is another way to solve this?

This is the structure of my application:

```
    KStream<String, Data> input =
        streamsBuilder.stream(dataTopic,
                              Consumed.with(Serdes.String(),
                                            new DataSerde(),
                                            new DataTimestampExtractor(),
                                            Topology.AutoOffsetReset.LATEST));

    KTable<String, Metadata> metadataTable =
        streamsBuilder.table(metadataTopic,
                             Consumed.with(Serdes.String(),
                                           new MetadataSerde(),
                                           new WhichTimestampExtractorToUse(),
                                           Topology.AutoOffsetReset.EARLIEST));

    input.leftJoin(metadataTable, this::joiner)
         .process(new ProcessorUsingPunctuateOnEventTime());
```

Comment: I think, returning zero as timestamp is a good approach.

Comment: Matthias, sorry for my late reply, thx for confirming the zero timestamp should work (I didn't notice any problems with it so far)